# Set Dokku ENV vars on first app push?

Tags: dokku

I am deploying an app which *requires* certain ENV vars to be set in order to run (app shuts down if they are not set).

When I try to deploy the app, I get the following error:

```
-----> Waiting for 10 seconds ...
remote: App container failed to start!!
```

this is because

1. The app can't start without certain ENV vars.
2. (as far as I know) I can't set Dokku ENV vars for an app that doesn't exist yet.

**Is it possible to set ENV vars when pushing an app for the first time?**

I tried to set the ENV vars before I push, but obviously:

```
ssh dokku@server config:set 00-default FOO=bar
App 00-default does not exist
```

**Additional Information:** I would prefer *not* to put the ENV vars in the procfile, because it is for an open source project. Putting configuration into source control would not be ideal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Create the app using `dokku apps:create <name>`
2. Set the ENV virables using `dokku config:set <name> <ENVS...>`
3. Push code